# How to split long commands containing special character into multiline commands?

Tags: yaml, gitlab

I have been reading documentation from gitlab at:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands

In my case I have a special character (colon ':'), so I also did read:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#use-special-characters-with-script

Now my question is: how do I combine both ?

On one hand I have ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/136285)):

```
job name:
  script:
    - |
      for file in *; do
        echo "$file";
        echo "${REPO}/${file}";
      done
```

And on the other hand I have ([ref](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/#publish-a-generic-package-by-using-cicd)):

```
  script:
    - 'for file in *; do curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" --upload-file "${file}" "${REPO}/${file}"; done'
```

How do I combine both ? Long term solution is to handle error in my `for` loop as ([ref](https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code)):

```
    - 'http_code=$(curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" --upload-file "$file" "${REPO}/${file}")'
    - if [ $http_code -ne 201 ]; then echo "Upload failed: terminating" && false; fi;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified my problem in moving the special character in the `variables` section. While still valid YAML, this seems to solve my symptoms:

```
job name:
  variables:
    token: "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN"
  script:
    - |
      for file in *; do
        http_code=$(curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" --header "$token" --upload-file "$file" "${REPO}/${file}")
        if [ $http_code -ne 201 ]; then echo "Upload failed for $file" && false; fi;
      done
```